ggplot2 breaks cowplot plot_grid could not find function "scales_add_defaults"
I am running the last version of ggplot2 (3.5.1( and cowplot (1.1.3.9). When plotting with plot_grid:
cowplot::plot_grid(rrplots[[1]],rrplots[[8]],rrplots[[15]],rrplots[[22]],rrplots[[29]],rrplots[[36]],ncol=3)

I get this error:
Error:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `scales_add_defaults()`:
! could not find function "scales_add_defaults"

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thanks!

Can you provide a fully reproducible example? In general plot_grid() works with ggplot2 3.5 as far as I know, so would be interested what specifically is going wrong here. Please make the example as minimal as possible so all irrelevant parts are removed. Use minimal, made-up data.

reverting to ggplot2 3.4.4 solves the problem...
